# How to create a datetime variable with millisecond in c#? (blazor)

Tags: c#, datetime

```
private Task OnProjectCreated()
{
    DateTime now = DateTime.Now.AddMilliseconds(1000);

    ProjectModel newProject = new ProjectModel
    {        
        ProjectName = "ProjectA",
        ProjectUpdated = now
    }

    _db.InsertProject(newProject);
    var currentProject = _db.GetProjectByTime<ProjectModel>(now);

    //here, the currentProject object is passing to the parent component(balzor)
    return ProjectCreated.InvokeAsync(currentProject);
    
}
```

> I want to fetch a project from database by DateTime but the DateTime variable 'now' has no milliseconds therefore I get an error like this 'Sequence contains no elements'. So I have added AddMilliseconds(1000) but it is still not working. I think that 'now' variable does not match with Project.ProjectUpdated which is saved in the database.
>
> > I have controlled the Project table in sql server management studio and there all ProjectUpdated are saved with milliseconds but when I use 'now' as an arg in _db.GetProjectByTime(now) has no milliseconds. How can I solve it?
> > Thank you in advance!

```
public ProjectModel GetProjectByTime<ProjectModel>(DateTime dateTime)
     {
         string sql = $"select * from Projects where ProjectUpdated = 
         '{dateTime}'";
         var data = _accessDb.GetData<ProjectModel>(sql);

         return data;
     }
```

> the problem is that, ProjectUpdated in db is saved like this:2021-06-07 17:46:28.747 but when I use 'now' as arg in _db.GetProjectByTime(now) it looks like this: 2021-06-07 17:46:28 I mean without milliseconds (as I have controlled by break points at running)

Comment: What is the problem?  No records returned? Then show the Database code. The query and everything related to the Model definition.

Comment: I have edited the code above. Thank you

Comment: I want actually to have a datetime variable with millisecond so that I can fetch a project by its ProjectUpdated property. All projects are saved in this format 2021-06-07 17:46:28.747 so I should have the same format in the variable 'now' _db.GetProjectByTime(now). but here when I use DateTime now = DateTime.Now; the 'now' seems to not have milliseconds. I have tried use AddMilliseconds(1000) but it s not working.

Comment: A DateTime has no 'format'. That only applies to a string representation. The type in your Db is still unclear.

Comment: thank you for your time. I have solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I changed the string sql to

```
string sql = $"select * from Projects where ProjectUpdated = CONVERT(datetime, '{dateTime}')";
```

> and this is working now without problem.

Comment: Hi, can you mark your question as answered please.

Comment: Hi, I can't vote my own answer nor mark the question as answered until 2 days.

Comment: NP.  I didn't know you had to wait 48 hours :-)